# В Java всё объекты?

Tags: java, объекты

Я читаю книгу и иногда в примере мы ссылаемся на переменную, а в книге описывается мол ссылаемся на объект. Вот эти слова:

> Когда метод вызывается, ему автоматически передается ссылка на
>   вызывающий объект, т.е. тот объект, для которого вызывается данный
>   метод. Эта ссылка обозначается ключевым словом `this`.

Для меня объект это экземпляр класса. Вот объявление/создание объекта.

```
Test test = new Test();
```

Объясните пожалуйста!

Показан вот такой пример:

```
public class Test {
    double b;
    int e;
    double val;
    Test(double base, int exp) {
        this.b = base;
        this.e = exp;
        this.val = 1;
        if(exp==0) return;
        for ( ; exp>0; exp-- ) this.val = this.val * base;
    }
    double get_pwr() {
        return this.val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Объекты здесь не вижу

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван при вставке цитат следует использовать специальную разметку(знак двойных кавычек в редакторе). Я уже выделил цитаты в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван P.S. И практически все слова связанные с программированием надо тоже помечать разметкой(не только код). Пример - слово `this`

Comment: В цитате нет намёка на то, что в Java всё является объектами. Речь там идёт только о том, что если вызван какой-то метод какого-то объекта (например, `get_pwr`), то `this` будет указывать на объект, для которого вызван этот метод

Comment: @Anton238, [не надо пихать везде выделение кодом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1338/186999) его нужно использовать только для кода.

Comment: @Grundy а словами "не только код" я хотел сказать, что надо выделять не только большие куски кода

Comment: @Anton238, из комментария кажется, что нужно выделять практически все.

Comment: @Grundy к сожалению, я уже не могу исправить комментарий,  но думаю, что автор поймет что нужно выделять, из нашего разговора.

Answer (score 1):

В [`Java`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) объекты - это только экземпляры классов, и все. В цитате говорится, что в методе у нас есть ссылка на объект класса(слово `this`). С помощью этой ссылки мы можем вызвать переменную/метод из класса. Слово `this` - это ссылка на экземпляр класса(только того класса, в котором оно используется). Т.е., `this.val` эквивалентно

```
double get_pwr() {
    Test test = this;
    return test.val;
}
```

Описание объекта с одного [старого сайта](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.1.php):

> Шаблоном или описанием объекта является класс, а объект представляет
>   экземпляр этого класса.

Comment: в таком случае double `get_pwr()` будет всегда возвращать `1`, т.к. вы будите возвращать поле `val` нового объекта, а не того, к которому обратился метод

Comment: @Mark не будет, т.к. код просто не скомпилиться, т.к. там просто нет конструктора по умолчанию. Я исправил.

Comment: `this` не эквивалентно `new Test(b, e);`, это совсем разные объекты. у объекта `this` поле `val` может иметь произвольное значение, совсем не то что у нового объекта только что из конструктора

Comment: @Mark `this`  не эквивалентно. Я имею ввиду, что используется так же - для вызова свойства по ссылке. Я исправлю

Answer (score -2):

Объекты представляют из себя совокупность примитивных типов и других объектов. Объекты можно сравнивать с помощью equals и hashcode. В первом случае сравниваются ссылочные типы на объект, во втором сравнивается хешкод. Подробнее вы можете узнать в интернете. Там как раз описываются свойства объектов. 
Что касается This - то это ссылочный тип на текущий объект.
Есть еще super - в данном случае мы ссылаемся на родительский элемент, это может быть имплементация или интерфейс.
Что касательно книги, то не стоит придираться к каждому слову, так как перевод может быть неправильным и некоторые слова не те. В переменные действительно можно использовать другие объекты и использовать их методы. Так что я соглашусь.

> "1. с помощью equals ... сравниваются ссылочные типы на объект" - мне
>   непонятна фраза. То ли речь про оператор == идёт, который сравнивает
>   ссылки, в отличие от equals, где может быть какая угодно логика
>   сравнения, то ли ещё про что-то. О чём идёт речь?

Если мы посмотрим реализацию метода equals, то мы увидим следующее:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (obj == this) {
    return true;
}
```

Т.е. отвечаю автору вопроса, метод equals является абсолютно тоже самым что и ==.
Но лучше использовать в практике метод equals, его можно переопределить на ваше усмотрение. Например:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        if (obj instanceof String) return true; 
           else return false;
    } else return false;
```

> 2. "super ... мы ссылаемся на родительский элемент" - что такое родительский элемент? Это определённо не родительский объект, ибо
>      такой штуки не существует

Родительский элементы является интерфейс или абстрактный класс.
Например:

```
public class LadaKalina implements Car
```

в данном случае родительский элемент это интерфейс Car, и методы у него будут, при вызове super, как у интерфейса Car.
Или пример с абстрактным классом. Чтобы не писать заново переопределение метода, мы вызываем super:

```
public abstract class Lada {
   public open() {
      System.out.println("Машина открыта");
   }
}

public class Kalina extends Lada {
   @Override
   public open() {
      super.open();
      System.out.println("Привет Алексей!");
      System.out.println("Добро пожаловать в Ладу Калину.");
      System.out.println("Это голосовой помощник Алиса.");
      System.out.println("Чем я могу быть вам полезна?");
   }
}
```

Вывод:

```
"Машина открыта"
"Привет Алексей!"
"Добро пожаловать в Ладу Калину. "
"Это голосовой помощник Алиса. "
"Чем я могу быть вам полезна?"
```

UPD 18.11.2018:
Специально для автора еще раз перечитал

> Core java (Java. Библиотека профессионала, том 1-2) Cay S. Horstmann (Кей С.
>   Хорстманн)

вопрос автора:

> 2. "super ... мы ссылаемся на родительский элемент" - что такое родительский элемент? Это определённо не родительский объект, ибо
>      такой штуки не существует

Такая «штука» как раз существует.

Я считаю свою формулировки и теперь правильными поскольку, (цитата из книги):

> Если родительские классы не предоставили переопределение, то по
>   умолчанию используется метод из конечного родительского класса Object
>   и поэтому вы остаетесь с методом Object#equals(Object o). В Object API
>   это то же самое, что и ==; то есть он возвращает true тогда и только
>   тогда, когда обе переменные относятся к одному и тому же объекту, если
>   их ссылки одно и то же. Таким образом, вы будете тестировать на
>   равенство объектов, а не на функциональное равенство.

Да, действительно, вы правы. Я писал не родительский класс, а родительский элемент. Как я мог совершить такую ошибку... Лично мне не понятна ваша логика претензий в плане формулировок. Это не поможет вам быстрей писать код. Мое субъективное мнение, что можно хоть обглататься формулировками, но это не поможет создавать эффективный код, причем еще когда подбивают сроки по проекту.

Что касается следующего вопроса автора:

> "Родительский элементы является интерфейс или абстрактный класс." - а
>   неабстрактный класс, от которого наследуется данный класс, почему не
>   входит в эту формулировку? Плюс цепочка может состоять более чем из
>   одного интерфейса/класса - должно быть в множественном числе тогда

Да, согласен. Но в С++ интерфейсов вообще нет. Там строится все на абстрактных классах. Сам вопрос как звучит? вроде как: `В Java всё объекты?` а не :

```
построение цепочек из более чем одного интерфейса/класса
```

Теперь сам ответ на главный вопрос. На этот ответ я наткнулся в Spring MVC. При передаче атрибутов в сессию. Фишка в том, что при передачи атрибутов в сессию мы можем указать строку, коллекцию, любой другой Object. Так как jdk «превращает» (надеюсь автор не придирется к этому слову) объекты в байт код. И фактически все что туда передается это объекты. А следовательно - В JAVA ВСЕ объекты, так как и String и Integer наслудуются от Object.

Вот небольшой пример из Spring MVC где передаются значение Integer, String, Map.

```
map = new MapResume(request).getResumeMap(page);

ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
model.setViewName("ResumeSearch");

model.addObject("list_prof_field", paramsDAO.getProfFields());

model.addObject("map_resume", map);

model.addObject("count_resume", countResume);
model.addObject("page_select", page);
model.addObject("page_begin", startPage);
model.addObject("page_end", endPage);
model.addObject("page_count", countPage);
```

Как видно по коду, мы передает и коллекцию и String и Integer. Но входной параметр у `addObject` это `Object`:

```
public ModelAndView addObject(Object attributeValue) {
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Compiled Code">
        /* 0: aload_0
         * 1: invokevirtual org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.getModelMap:()Lorg/springframework/ui/ModelMap;
         * 4: aload_1
         * 5: invokevirtual org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.addAttribute:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/ui/ModelMap;
         * 8: pop
         * 9: aload_0
         * 10: areturn
         *  */
        // </editor-fold>
    }
```

Именно поэтому в JAVA ВСЕ объекты, отвечаю на главный вопрос.
Мой ответ вполне обоснованный, надеюсь он удовлетворит автора.

Comment: 1. _"с помощью equals ... сравниваются ссылочные типы на объект"_ - мне непонятна фраза. То ли речь про оператор `==` идёт, который сравнивает ссылки, в отличие от `equals`, где может быть какая угодно логика сравнения, то ли ещё про что-то. О чём идёт речь? 2. _"super ... мы ссылаемся на родительский элемент"_ - что такое родительский элемент? Это определённо не родительский объект, ибо такой штуки не существует

Comment: @Regent обновил вопрос. Посмотрите.

Comment: _"метод equals является абсолютно тоже самым что и =='_ - нет, в общем случае не является "тем же самым". И вы ниже сами пишете почему: его можно переопределить и добавить в него какую угодно логику, которая не будет совпадать с логикой ==. Претензия была именно к формулировке, в которой вы частный случай работы метода equals в Object почему-то обобщаете. Вопросы бы не было, если бы вы написали что-нибудь в стиле "по умолчанию (реализация в классе Object) метод equals работает так же, как ==, но метод equals можно переопределить в своем классе"

Comment: _"Родительский элементы является интерфейс или абстрактный класс."_ - а неабстрактный класс, от которого наследуется данный класс, почему не входит в эту формулировку? Плюс цепочка может состоять более чем из одного интерфейса/класса - должно быть в множественном числе тогда

Comment: @Regent я вам объяснить пытаюсь в своем понимании. Я старался, объяснял, в час ночи причем еще. А вы каждое мое высказывание критикуете. Я не вижу смысла вести дальнейший диалог, так как вы не настроены на его конструктивное разрешение. Зачем тем более задавать вопрос, если вы и сами знаете на него ответ.

Comment: @Regent обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Regent вам еще повезло, а я вообще не понял сначала, что значит значит фраза про "родительский элементы".

Comment: И String MVC тут не причем, и даже если вы хотите что-то показать на его основе, то автор вопроса все равно не поймет.

Comment: @Anton238 откуда вы знаете что не поймет. Может умный и понимающий человек. Мое субъективное мнение - глупо считать, что вас окружают одни идиоты. Умные люди тоже есть.